# Run a Macro through select cells

Tags: vba, excel, cell, selected

I need this macro to apply "Pass" to every individual cell in my selection. At the moment, even if I select multiple Cells, it only writes Pass on the first one that I selected.

I'm pretty new to this whole codding thing so I know I did something wrong.

```
Dim rngMyRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngMyRange = Selection
For Each cell In rngMyRange.Cells
ActiveCell = "Pass"
Next cell 

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `ActiveCell` to `cell`

Comment: Haha wow. Thanks a lot :) Such a small change that fixed everything!

Comment: Is there a way to select your answer as the best, and my case as resolved?

Comment: I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Now just click on the green check mark by the answer and it will then be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a For Each loop.  The variable, in this case `cell` represents each cell as it iterates.  So changing the loop to this:

```
For Each cell In rngMyRange.Cells
    cell = "Pass"
Next cell
```

should do the trick.

ActiveCell only refers to the actual active cell and the loop does not change which cell is active.  It is considered bad form to activate a cell in a loop, as it slows down the code.

Comment: Thanks again for this :)